# C++ Modulus operator Vs. Shift operator, which is faster and why?

Tags: c++, time, bit-shift

I was working on the code to find prime number, and during my work i became curious how exactly % operation in C++ works in low level.

Firstly, I wrote some code to compare elapsed time of '%' operator and '>>' operator, each.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

bool remainder1(int x);
bool remainder2(int y);
void timeCompare(bool(*f)(int), bool(*g)(int));

// I want to check which one is faster, x % 2 Vs. (x >> 1) & 1
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        timeCompare(remainder1, remainder2);
    }

    return 0;
}

// % 2 operation
bool remainder1(int x) {

    if (x % 128) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool remainder2(int x) {

    if ((x >> 7) & 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

void timeCompare(bool(*f)(int), bool(*g)(int)) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        int x = rand();
        f(x);
    }

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds : "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " ns";


    auto start2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        int x = rand();
        g(x);
    }

    auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();


    cout << " Vs. "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - start2).count()
         << " ns" << endl;


}
```

And the output is this :

```
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 166158000 ns Vs. 218736000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 151776000 ns Vs. 214823000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 162193000 ns Vs. 217248000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 151338000 ns Vs. 211793000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 150346000 ns Vs. 211295000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 155799000 ns Vs. 215265000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 148801000 ns Vs. 212839000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 149813000 ns Vs. 226175000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 152324000 ns Vs. 213338000 ns
Elapsed time in nanoseconds : 149353000 ns Vs. 216809000 ns
```

So it seems like shift operation is slower in finding remainder. I guessed the reason is that shift version needs one more comparison than '%' version... Am I correct?

I really want to know how '%' works in lower level!

Comment: The modulus operation should be slower, but your function is probably optimised into something like `return x & 127;` and now it has fewer operations than your bitshift version. Also note that your second function doesn't really do the same thing as the first (it would if you wanted to find the remainder when dividing by 2 though, but then you would shift by 0 and that's a bit odd).

Comment: As a side note, bit shift operations should be used on unsigned integers. Using them on signed integers could cause issues, it most likely won't, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I’m guessing you didn’t have compiler optimisation enabled (i.e. you used the debug build), otherwise your timing loops should have been optimised away.

Comment: Open it up in your debugger and look at the assembly for your code.

Comment: It should be obvious that C++ has nothing to say on how fast shift or modulus operators are. It's entirely down to the compiler and the hardware. Change either of those and your results may vary.

Comment: Pet peeve: `if (...) return true else return false` instead of `return ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I really want to know how '%' works in lower level!

If you're asking how it is implemented then the answer is that chances are  **the CPU you're using has a *single* instruction for modulo** (`%`). For example, take this C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 100;

    int mod = x % 128;
    int shift = x >> 7;

    return 0;
}
```

The generated *x86* assembly code (Clang 6.0.0) for it is:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     ecx, 128
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 100
    mov     edx, dword ptr [rbp - 8]  # Start of modulo boilerplater
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 20], eax 
    mov     eax, edx
    cdq
    idiv    ecx                       # Modulo CPU instruction
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], edx # End of modulo sequence
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 8]  # Start of shift boilerplate
    sar     ecx, 7                    # Shift CPU instruction
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 16], ecx # End of shift sequence
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 20]
    mov     eax, ecx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

The [`idiv` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) is called the *Signed Divide*, and it places the quotient in EAX/RAX and the remainder in EDX/RDX for (x86/x64 accordingly).

> I guessed the reason is that shift version needs one more comparison
>   than '%' version... Is my correct?

No comparisons are being done in this case, since it's a single instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Actually, my guess was that remainder1 function is faster than remainder2 function because remainder2 function uses '>>' and  '&', on the other hand remainder1 function only uses '%'. Is this correct guess? Sorry for making it unclear.

Comment: @TonyAhn Well you can see for yourself [here live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nlv7wMD3aaBulDhh) if this is the case -- I dropped the `&` in `remainder2()` and the timings speak for themselves : )